# Still struggling to pass JSON object along with a url param to a php file.Any ideas how?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

```
  // Creating variables to hold data from textboxes. First building associated details
  myData.Token = $("#token").val();
  myData.BuildingDisplay = $("#BuildingDisplay").val();
  myData.FeatureID = $("#FeatureID").val();
  myData.BuildingID = $("#BuildingID").val();
  myData.Address = $("#Address").val();
  myData.City = $("#City").val();
  myData.District = $("#District").val();
  myData.Location = $("#Location").val();
  myData.State = $("#State").val();
  myData.StreetName = $("#StreetName").val();
  myData.Zip = $("#Zip").val();
  myData.X = $("#X").val();
  myData.Y = $("#Y").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "proxyCheck.php",
  data: "{ 'Token': '" + mytoken + "','Address': '" + myaddress + "', 'City': '" + mycity + "','Location': '" + mylocation + "','State': '" + mystate + "', 'StreetName': '" + mystreetname + "', 'Zip': '" + myzip + "', 'X': '" + myX + "', 'Y': '" + myY + "'}",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function (response) {
    alert("Record has been added successfully.");
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

When above data is formatted into JSON object, it is presented in the following format:

```
{data: 
      {
        "token":"73264280-be3f-4f5b",
        "BuildingDisplay":"Fire Station 21 Fairburn - 19 East Broad St.",
        "CallerEmail":"Jim.Parker@yahoo.com",
        "CallerFax":"",
        "CallerFirstName":"Jim",
        "CallerLastName":"Parker",
        "CallerMiddleInitial":"",
        "CallerOtherPhone":"",
        "CallerState":"",
        "CallerWorkPhone":"918-354-2874"}}
```

What I would like to do is pass them to proxyCheck.php in the following:

```
 proxyCheck.php?data={data: 
      {
        "token":"73264280-be3f-4f5b",
        "BuildingDisplay":"Fire Station 21 Fairburn - 19 East Broad St.",
        "CallerEmail":"Jim.Parker@yahoo.com",
        "CallerFax":"",
        "CallerFirstName":"Jim",
        "CallerLastName":"Parker",
        "CallerMiddleInitial":"",
        "CallerOtherPhone":"",
        "CallerState":"",
        "CallerWorkPhone":"918-354-2874"}}&token=73264280-be3f-4f5b
```

Please notice **&token=73264280-be3f-4f5b**

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Can someone please help?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proxyCheck.php?token=" + myData.Token,
     data: JSON.stringify(myData)
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Record has been added successfully.");
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
  return false;
 }
```

//proxyCheck.php

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init("http://domain/UserServices/Create");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $output
 ?>
```

//*************************************

//AJAX

```
var uname = $("#user").val();
var upass = $("#pass").val();

$.post("proxyValidate.php",
  { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: uname,Password: upass }) })
    .done(function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        switch(result.Status) {
            case 0:
                //login successful
                tokenVal = result.Value.Token;
                location.href = "http://domain/userService.php?token="+tokenVal;
                break;

            case 2:
                //invalid login
                alert(result.Message);
                break;
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("The AJAX request failed!");
    });
  });
```

//proxyValidate

```
  <?php

    $ch = curl_init("http://domain/Validation/Validate");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output
  ?>
```

Comment: Don't try to build json strings by concatenation. Create a javascript object (like `myData`?) and call `JSON.stringify()`. Also, why are you expecting url parameters if you're doing a post? The data should be in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may run into similar problem as me, here is the solution that worked for me:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proxyCheck.php?token",
    data: {
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        token: myData.Token
    },
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Record has been added successfully.");
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to convert the javascript object to a string - jQuery will do this for you.  Try this...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proxyCheck.php?token=" + myData.Token,
    data: myData,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Record has been added successfully.");
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

There's a slight issue with variable names being case sensitive (token and Token, for example), but the above code should post what you need, as well as have the token value in the URL.

Alternatively, if you need to pass the data as a string then you can do the following...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proxyCheck.php?token=" + myData.Token,
    data: {
        data: JSON.stringify(myData)
    },
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Record has been added successfully.");
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: If he specifies object as "data" parameter in jQuery post, jquery will convert it to parameters. He specifically said that he needs to pass the json, which means that he should convert it to string first.

Comment: @D.Kasipovic Good point - I'll amend the answer to include that option.

Comment: The `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` is incorrect here.  This is the content type of the request body.  In both examples, the `data` will be converted to a query string, so it's not JSON.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The data won't be converted to a querystring since it's a post, not a get.

Comment: @Archer: Yes it will.  The query string will be sent via the post body.  That's why you shouldn't be sending the `application/json` header.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Post data is converted into name/value pairs but is still not passed as a querystring.  I don't think I'm understanding your point here as it definitely won't be part of the URL.

Comment: @Archer: Maybe "query string" isn't the right term here, but all I am trying to say here is that you should remove the `contentType` option.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks - that is what was throwing me.  It's there purely because it was in the question code.  I never use it personally, as I trust jQuery to handle most of the ajax options by default.  I'll remove it from the answer since you believe it's not relevant - thanks :)

Comment: @Archer: What that option does is *override* the `Content-type` header sent in the AJAX request.  By default it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  If you change this, PHP won't auto-populate the `$_POST` array :-D  Sorry to confuse you and use the wrong terms :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat, you are correct!

I remove that and it formats it beautifully but I still don't understand why I am getting a response below:

`{"Value":null,"Status":2,"Message":"No auth token`

I want to thank you all especiall Archer for your assistance with this.

Still need a bit more of your expertise to figure out why the API is not receiving the token.

Comment: I have no idea about your response as we've not got any code to show what you do with this data once it's posted.

Comment: @Archer, the data is posted to a file called proxyCheck.php. I have posted the code for proxyCheck.php above at the bottom. 

Sorry for too much code.

This code then passes it to an API method called Create. That file I can't see because it sits at vendors site.

We have to go from AJAX to proxyCheck.php to get around Same Domain issue. It works with our authentication but not working here.

Comment: Can you either contact the vendor or do you have documentation that will help?  Unless you can show us data that does work and then data that doesn't work you're stuck with asking the vendor.

Comment: @Archer, hope you are still here. I have posted the code that works.

The AJAX portion of the code receives two params from the form, similar to the one we are having issues.

It then passes the those params formatted as JSON data, to proxyValidate.php.

This php file in turn passes those params to Validate API method.

It returns 0 when valid and then generates the token that we are using now.

This works great. I followed similar approach to handling this one but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You really should use POST for that kind of data. If you insist on using GET as you suggested, you should urlencode the JSON, but still, it could easily happen that you url gets too long an thus unable to be open.

EDIT: A solution that should work, by @Archer

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proxyCheck.php?token=" + myData.Token,
    data: {
        data: JSON.stringify(myData)
    },
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Record has been added successfully.");
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Archer,

Thank you so much.

The problem is that I continue to get the following message when I run the code:

`  {"Value":null,"Status":2,"Message":"No auth token supplied."}`

For some reason, the API that the proxyCheck.php is passing the token to isn't seeing it for some reason.

Plus the values are not getting passed in JSON format such as {"name: "john doe"...} for instance. Instead I am getting these (just a short example):

`Token=1e321699-5413-4c98-b3ec-5c2d98339659&BuildingDisplay=Amersee+Lakes+Pump+Station+Pump+Station+-+9100+Etching`

Comment: If you want to pass json by post, you should stringify it first, i.e. convert it to string and then pass it.

Comment: @JsonP, Dkasipovi, I did convert it to Json.stringify. Please update above.

Comment: Try with `data: { 'data' : JSON.Stringify(myData) }`

Comment: @DKasipovic, it is not me although I don't see where I am using GET.

Comment: http://host/link.php?id=1&a=b&c=d is link which is using get as parameter transfer method. When using post, parameters are not visible in the link.

Comment: @Archer, et al, please see above the result I am getting when I run your code. It is at the bottom of my post above.

I just keep getting this message:

`{"Value":null,"Status":2,"Message":"No auth token` which means it is not getting the passed token. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Archer has adjusted his answer, you should adjust your script accordingly.

Comment: @Dkasipovic, I did.

I am viewing the results on Network of firefox.

Comment: Your script says `data: '{data: ' + JSON.stringify(myData) + '}'` and his says `data: { data: JSON.stringify(myData) }`. I do not see how that is the same?

Comment: @Dkasipovic, I am using his. Sorry I just posted the wrong one.

Please see it again above.

Comment: You are still not using his.

Comment: @DKasipovic, Can you please post the correct one here then?

Comment: I have edit my answer, but this is getting too long and complicated, you should have enough by now to resolve this on your own, unless you expect a complete solution.

Comment: @DKasipovic, if that's the change you made, I already have that. That's the point I was making by asking you to post it. The code you posted is no different from what I already have.

And yes, I need complete solution because I am still having issues.

Comment: Well, either you do not see well, or I do not see well. Your change says `data: JSON.stringify(myData)` and mine says `data: {
        data: JSON.stringify(myData)
    }` Am I missing something here?

Comment: @DKasipovic,

No worries friend. Thanks for all your help.

If you read further up on the communication between Archer, myselft and Rocket, you will notice that I acknowledged that the solution from Archer works as far as returning json formatted data like it is supposed to be but the API still can't see any token.

Comment: Well, you should really include your most current code in the edit.